# What to add in HTML code to be printed into CSV or output as CSV

Tags: html, csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wydo.png)I am able to create & print below in HTML but not how to sure convert or add something to print it into CSV file or CSV outout.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
      <TABLE border="1">
        <?relevance
tr of concatenation of (th of "Computer Name" & th of "Support Group" & th of "Last Report Time" & th of "BES Relay Service Installed" & th of "OS Platform" & th of "Is BES Infrastructure") & concatenation of trs of (td of (item 0 of it as string) & td of (item 1 of it as string) & td of (item 2 of it as string) & td of (item 3 of it as string) & td of (item 4 of it as string) & td of (item 5 of it as string)) of (name of it, values of results from (bes property "Support Group") of it, last report time of it, values of results from (bes property "BES Relay Service Installed") of it, values of results from (bes property "OS Platform (Windows or Unix)") of it, values of results from (bes property "Is BES Infrastructure") of it) of bes computers whose (last report time of it < (now - 3*hour) AND (value of results from (bes property "BES Relay Service Installed") of it starts with  "Yes") AND (value of results from (bes property "Is BES Infrastructure") of it starts with "True") AND (value of results from (bes property "Support Group") of it contains "GTO") ) 
?>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you need to give more context and what we are seeing and why? what is not working, what are you expecting to happen. All i see is a blob of html, poorly formatted.

Comment: Above code is from our custom webreport if I put this code there, it will give me output of provided fields into HTML format which perfectly working fine no gap in here.
but if output is for 10K machines then HTML page will take lot of time to process & show in HTML hence I want something to put in this code which help in producing CSV output, I tried in-built function to export HTML results in CSV but thats all being copied in one line.

Comment: I want to showcase the results of it but since I am new this form its not allowing pasting image file

Comment: google html table to csv.... is that what you trying  to do.,

Comment: no that is pretty simple, there are lot of tool & online web available for that, I cant go & put confidential data over there.
If you can help me with some code which can help to divert HTML output to CSV in same HTML code that will be great help.